# How to disable going back after log in?

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to make a simple log in page but the problem is the user can go back from index page to the log in page, I tried using exit; but it didn't work.

```
 header("location: index.php",TRUE,302); 
 exit;
```

I also tried using this code but it didn't work:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: Check from your session if the user is logged in, only display the login form if user's logged in, else redirect to index.

Comment: Delete the session variable once user logged out. If there is no session variable set, redirect to another page

Comment: @vanamerongen I did what you said but it didn't work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I just added this code at the top of my log in page:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set any coockie or session value after loged in, you need to check very first in your login file if cookie or session value set redirect into your index page.

Comment: or try this code in your index file.`<script type = "text/javascript" >
   function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>'